# How to get the locale in Symfony 2.1 controller?

Tags: symfony-2.1

I installed, the bundle: https://github.com/lunetics/LocaleBundle which help to switch between language. Everything works fine, in twig, translation works fine. But when i want to translate any message in the controller, i get french (fr) instead of defined language (en for example).

Please how can i get the current selected locale in the controller ?

i use: `$this->getRequest()->getLocale()` but it does not work, it give me FR for each culture.

my default setting language in parameter.ini is FR

Answer (score 0):

After looking inside the code of LuneticsLocaleBundle and Symfony 2.1 Documentation, i discovred that, symfony2.1 is passing the Locale in route. The problem exists when rendering an action from twig template, where symfony creates nes request. So, to resolve this, i override the code of LuneticsLocaleBundle and i added `$this->get('session')->set('_locale', $_locale);` in the switchAction of LocaleController of the bundle.

So, the locale, will be stored in session.

I hope that can helps you too.